# How to fetch and keep updated data with flutter_hooks?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I'm studying flutter_hooks library. My aim is to fetch data into model and be able to refresh it any time. Also I'd like to refresh data from different screens. Currently I do it this way:

Page class:

```
class NewPage extends HookWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final holder=useState<ModelHolder>(ModelHolder()).value;
    final notifier=useListenable(holder.notifier);
    final model=notifier.value;
    final refresh=useState<bool>(false);
    useEffect(()  {
      print('refetching');
      holder.fetch();
    },[refresh.value]);
    print('model:$model, ${model.hashCode}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          refresh.value=!refresh.value;//trigger refresh
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

ModelHolder class:

```
class ModelHolder {
  final ValueNotifier<Model?> notifier = ValueNotifier<Model?>(null);

  void fetch() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));//do server call
    notifier.value=Model('data');
  }
}
```

Model class:

```
class Model{
  final String value;
  Model(this.value);
}
```

Basically this code works as expected. The only thing I'm confused is refresh variable in the `NewPage`. Due to this I can't extract hook's logic into custom hook. This is a typical task. I suspect that I'm inventing a wheel. What is the right way of fetching/updating data with flutter_hooks?

UPD: I moved refresh property into `ModelHolder` and now able to isolate everything in a custom hook.

holder:

```
class ModelHolder {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> refresher;
  final ValueNotifier<Model?> notifier = ValueNotifier<Model?>(null);

  ModelHolder(this.refresher);

  void fetch() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));//do server call
    notifier.value=Model('data');
  }
}
```

Custom hook:

```
ModelHolder useModel(){
  final refresh=useState<bool>(false);
  final holder=useState(ModelHolder(refresh)).value;
  useListenable(holder.notifier);
  useEffect(()  {
    print('refetching');
    holder.fetch();
  },[refresh.value]);
  return holder;
}
```

Usage:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final holder=useModel();
    ...
}
```

And I can pass `holder` to other routes to update it from there.